# Error: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value

Tags: solidity, remix

I am building the following smart contract on Remix and I'm currently receiving these errors when trying to call addBook("Goosebumps", "RL Stine", 1).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Library {

    struct Book {
        uint256 id;
        bytes32 title;
        bytes32 author;
        CoverType cover;
    }

    enum CoverType { HardCover, Paperback }

    uint256 lastBookId;
    mapping(uint256 => Book) books;

    function addBook(bytes32 _title, bytes32 _author, CoverType _cover) public {
        lastBookId++;
        Book memory newBook;
        newBook = Book(lastBookId, _title, _author, _cover);
    }
}
```

From [Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_strings.htm) they state

> In Solidity we can assign String literal to a byte32 type variable easily. Solidity considers it as a byte32 literal.
>
> ```
> contract SolidityTest {
>   bytes32 data = "test";
> }
> ```

Am I missing something? Here's the error that prints to the console.

```
transact to Library.addBook errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="Goosebumps", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For pass bytes32 value you must convert your string (in this case) in exadecimal and after this operation you must to add remaining zeros needed get a hexadecimal of length 64 (without 0x).

Example:

Word: "test"

Exadecimal: 227465737422

Bytes32: 0x2274657374220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

In the last operation you must add 0x before 64 characters.